# Plot a graph using data in the table below

Tags: javascript, graph, charts

I want to plot a graph using the below table data. It contains the number of MBs consumed during the specified period. I need a graph of MBs vs the Time Period.
Is there any easy to use JS library/framework available that can be used to plot the graph. This data would be available in html table form and can contain entries up to one month data. If not in JS can we plot it in any other language Java etc.

`IPADDRESS  MAC ADDRESS         FROM                        TO          USAGE(MB)
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 21:08:25.0   2016-08-21 21:08:50.0   6.209942
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 17:08:25.0   2016-08-21 21:08:25.0   427.361991
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 13:08:25.0   2016-08-21 17:08:25.0   317.248562
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 11:08:07.0   2016-08-21 13:08:25.0   309.770084
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 11:08:06.0   2016-08-21 11:08:07.0   0.000686
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 09:08:25.0   2016-08-21 11:08:06.0   452.716015
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 05:08:25.0   2016-08-21 09:08:25.0   394.039499
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-21 01:08:25.0   2016-08-21 05:08:25.0   29.168815
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-20 21:08:25.0   2016-08-21 01:08:25.0   1172.659576
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-20 17:08:25.0   2016-08-20 21:08:25.0   1368.401099
ipaddress   macaddress  2016-08-20 13:08:25.0   2016-08-20 17:08:25.0   759.810482`

Comment: Take a look at google charts and come back when you have some actual code for us to help you with: [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

Comment: I will try these and come with more questions if any

Answer (score 0):

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

Super easy to use, and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get started, you could use the JavaScript libraries [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) or  [c3.js](http://c3js.org/).